# How do I find all $x$ values without using determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I want to find all values of $x$ for which the following matrix is invertible.

$$\begin{pmatrix} x - \frac12 & 0 & 0\\ x & x - \frac13 & 0\\ x^2 & x^3 & x + \frac14\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that using lower triangular determinant (at $x$ values where determinant not equal to zero), I can find easily, but I want to find using reduced echelon form. How can I do that?

Comment: Hint: think about the condition on det $\neq0$ via eigenvalues

Comment: Divide the problem into four cases: $x = 1/2, x = 1/3, x = -1/4$, and all remaining values of $x$. For the first $3$ cases, note that we have a zero entry on the diagonal and conclude for each case that the reduced echelon form has a zero-row. For the final case, divide each row by the diagonal value and row-reduce the matrix to get the identity matrix.

Comment: @jjjjjj : I know it, but I don't want to use determinant rules. I want to find x values using reduce echelon form. If I used determinant, It would be very easy (except 1/2,1/3,−1/4, all x values)

Comment: @BenGrossmann: when I divided each row by the diagonal value, should I say that x values can be all real numbers except $1/2, 1/3$ and $-1/4$ because in that case, the denominator could be zero, so it is a contradiction. Is it correct, sir?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=\frac12$, than all entries of the first row are zeros, and therefore the matrix is not invertible.

Assume now that $x\ne\frac12$. Then divide the first row by $x-\frac12$, and you will get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\x&x-\frac13&0\\x^2&x^3&x+\frac14\end{bmatrix}.$$Now you add to the second row the first row times $-x$ and you add to the third row the first row times $-x^2$; you will get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&x-\frac13&0\\0&x^3&x+\frac14\end{bmatrix}.$$If $x=\frac13$, the the second row only has zeros, and therefore the matrix is not invertible.

Assume now that $x\ne\frac13$. Then divide the second row by $x-\frac13$. You will get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&x^3&x+\frac14\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, add to the third row the second row times $-x^3$. You will get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&x+\frac14\end{bmatrix}.$$

If $x=-\frac14$, the third row only has zeros, and therefore the matrix is not invertible. Otherwise, divide the third row by $x+\frac14$. Then you will get the identity matrix, which is invertible. So, the original matrix will also be invertible.